# Navigating between User Control Pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, app.xaml

I'm thing to navigate between pages while keeping the same original page

The Code in MainPage.xaml is

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MainPage.View"

<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <views:Page1 x:Name="InterfacePage"/>
</Grid>
```

Page1 in a User Control Page with a button in it. When I press that button I would like to change Page1 to Page2 another User Control Page without changing the MainPage

I've been searching but can't find anything on this
By the way I'm doing this using the windows Phone 8 sdk
Thanks

Comment: windows 8 sdk or Windows Phone 8 sdk ? Is it a WP 7 app or targeted for WP8 ?

Comment: Windows Phone 8 SDK aimed for windows phone 8 devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ButtonClick event of the Page1, try this

```
Button_Click()
{
    var contentPanel = (this.Parent as Grid);
    Page2 page2 = new Page2() { Name = "AnotherPage" };

    contentPanel.Children.Remove(this);
    contentPanel.Children.Add(page2);
}
```

Comment: Was wondering if you can point me in the direction of more information so i can learn more

Comment: What kind of information you want? [Ask here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17226/windows-phone-7-8)

Comment: a good source to help me learn C# and Xaml languages i work better with examples thanks